# Turn …/?token=xx-xxx into …/xx-xxx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess-file that removes index.php (codeigniter). I am having a problem with Paypal, cause the return url is using query strings, which are troublesome in codeigniter.

This is my htaccess-file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to rewrite the following example url-s:

```
http://.../site/bookingconfirmed/?token=EC-56G61173NH540131H
```

to

```
http://.../site/bookingconfirmed/EC-56G61173NH540131H
```

and

```
http://.../site/bookingdeclined/?token=EC-56G61173NH540131H
```

to

```
http//.../site/bookingdeclined/EC-56G61173NH540131H
```

Any good ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} token=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(site/booking.*)/?$ $1/%1? [L]
```

This'll make sure the trailing slash is in place too, so a request to `/site/bookingconfirmed?token=EC-56G61173NH540131H` will work as well.  And it throws away the query string - I'm assuming there's nothing else in there you need to keep?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.. very un-tested

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^site/(bookingconfirmed|bookingdeclined)/\?token\=(.*)$ /site/$1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You probably don't need the `[R=301,L]` bit - after the request URI is processed by your new rule, the rewritten version should just hit the last rule and be ... er, re-rewritten to go to index.php.